# Easy proof that $n=5$ is the only solution of $n^n \equiv n^{n^n} \pmod {10^{n-1}}$ if $n \in \mathbb{N}-\{0,1\}$ is not a multiple of $10$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, power-towers, hyperoperation

Let $n > 1$ be an integer not a multiple of $10$.
Is there a short proof that $n = 5$ is the only solution to $n^n \equiv n^{n^n} \pmod {10^{n-1}}$, given the fact that $5^{5^5} \equiv 3125 \pmod{10^4}$ (and even $3125 \equiv 5^{5^5} \pmod{10^5}$)?

P.S.
This question is related to my research on the congruence speed of tetration and arose in the discussion of the OEIS sequence $A369826$ before it was finally approved. Moreover, I am planning to submit another sequence concerning the number of frozen rightmost digits of some tetration bases at a given height (as my pending sequences are processed), and I would like to add also a short explanation in the comments that does not invoke the congruence speed of $n$ (i.e., for any integer $n>5$ that is not a multiple of $10$, the number of frozen digits at height $2$ cannot exceed three times the constant congruence speed of the base, which is given by Equation (16) of [Number of stable digits of any integer tetration](https://nntdm.net/volume-28-2022/number-3/441-457/), and then the stated result trivially follows).

Comment: where did this question come from? Context please. This looks like it **could be** interesting indeed, but whoever is going to attempt to answer this deserve to know, IMO, whether this came from homework, a contest, or if instead it is as open as the Riemann Hypothesis.

Comment: This question arose by discussing in the comments the OEIS sequence $A369826$ before it was finally approved. I have a proof that follows from my definition of "congruence speed", but it would be too long/complex for a comment on the OEIS (I am planning to submit another sequence when my pending sequences will be processed).

Comment: P.S. The constraint $10 \nmid n$ comes from the property discussed here https://arxiv.org/abs/2402.07929.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, Marco. A very interesting question indeed! +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A relatively short proof that the only non-multiple of $10$ with $n \gt 1$ which is a solution to

$$n^n(n^{n^n-n} - 1) \equiv 0 \pmod{10^{n-1}} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

is $5$ involves handling several cases, while also using the [Lifting-the-exponent lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting-the-exponent_lemma) (LTE lemma).

**Case #$1$**: $2 \nmid n$, $5 \mid n$ and $n \ge 15$

Since $5^{n-1} \mid n^n$, we just need to check if

$$n^{n^n-n} - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{2^{n-1}} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Since $2 \mid n - 1$ and $n^n - n$ is even, the LTE lemma gives

$$\nu_2(n^{n^n-n} - 1) = \nu_2(n-1) + \nu_2(n+1) + \nu_2(n^n - n) - 1 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Using the LTE lemma with $n^n - n = n(n^{n-1} - 1)$ results in

$$\nu_2(n^n - n) = \nu_2(n-1) + \nu_2(n+1) + \nu_2(n-1) - 1 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Substituting this into \eqref{eq3A}, and using that $\nu_2(n-1)$ or $\nu_2(n+1)$ is $1$, shows that

$$\nu_2(n^{n^n-n} - 1) = 3\nu_2(n-1) + 2\nu_2(n+1) - 2 \lt 3\lceil\log_2(n-1)\rceil \lt n - 1 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

This means \eqref{eq2A} and, thus also \eqref{eq1A}, don't hold.

**Case #$2$**: $2 \mid n$ and $5 \nmid n$

Since $2^{n-1} \mid n^n$, the only check required here is if

$$n^{n^n-n} - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{5^{n-1}} \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

There are several cases depending on $n \mod 5$. First, if $n \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$, then the LTE lemma shows that

$$\nu_5(n^{n^n-n} - 1) = \nu_5(n-1) + \nu_5(n^n - n) \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

Using the LTE lemma again with $n^n - n = n(n^{n-1} - 1)$ gives

$$\nu_5(n^n - n) = \nu_5(n-1) + \nu_5(n-1) \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

This in \eqref{eq7A}, and using that $n \ge 6$, we get

$$\nu_5(n^{n^n-n} - 1) = 3\nu_5(n-1) \lt n - 1 \tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$

This shows that \eqref{eq6A} and, thus also \eqref{eq1A}, don't hold.

Similar arguments can be used with the other congruencies, although starting from a base of $n^2 - 1$ with $n \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$ and, if applicable (i.e., we require that $4 \mid n$), a base of $n^4 - 1$ with $n \equiv 2,3 \pmod{5}$.

**Case #$3$**: $2 \nmid n$ and $5 \nmid n$

We need both \eqref{eq2A} and \eqref{eq6A} to hold, with the same basic arguments as in case #$1$ and #$2$ being used to show there are no solutions for this case either.